# a term that means "number of classes" (in a classification)

Tags: terminology, synonyms

I'm searching a word that could replace the phrase "number of classes".

In detail, I'm writing a paper in which I'm speaking about a classification method, and the number of classes is one of its parameters. I would like to use a one-word term as a name for this parameter.

I thought about "granularity" but unfortunately, this term is used to represent another well-known concept in the same domain I'm working on. So, I would avoid it. Coarseness and graininess, although known to be synonyms of granularity, they do not have the exact meaning I'm searching for, which is the degree of division in a classification.

Thank you.

Comment: Like **scope**?

Comment: Call the parameter *number_of_classes* or *num_classes* or *nb_classes* or...

Comment: Would *taxa* work?

Comment: In my COBOL days, we called it numclasses or if that was too long, numclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **granularity** is the correct word, but since that is out of court, I'd consider the following options:

1. **Specificity**:
   "The quality or condition of being specific" (M-W). The more granular the sub-divisions, the more specific they become.
2. **Narrowness** or **Width**:
   Width is defined by M-W as "largeness of extent or scope". Narrowness as "limited in size or scope". The *bins* to which @satnam refers are often described as *narrow* or *wide*. Naturally, wide bins can contain more data.
3. **Degree of Aggregation** or **Disaggregation**:
   Data collected together from disparate groups is said to be aggregated, when it is separated is is said to be disaggregated. According to M-W, aggregation can be defined as "the collecting of units or parts into a mass or whole".

Answer (score 2):

Does '[enumeration](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/enumeration)' suit your situation ?

> <sub><sup>NOUN</sup></sub>
>   the action of mentioning a number of things one by one.
>   "(e.g.) *the complete enumeration of all possible genetic states* "

(Oxford Dictionaries)

or '[compendium](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compendium)' -

> 3. a full list or inventory:
>      *a compendium of their complaints.*

(*Random House Dictionary*, via Dictionary.com)

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! This is a good first answer. I've added citations and links to what I take to be the sources of your definitions, to bring it in line with our usual standards. If I got the sources wrong or you'd prefer to do this differently, please feel free to roll back the changes or make further edits. It can also be helpful to add a line or two of your own, explaining why you think the suggestion fits the OP's particular circumstances. Good luck!

Comment: By using enumeration and compendium we have to add "of classes" to obtain the complete meaning. Actually, I'm searching one word that could be understood without adding "of classes".

Answer (score 0):

In statistics, '**bins**' is used to the same effect. [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bin) states its meaning as

> Each of a series of ranges of numerical value into which data are sorted in statistical analysis

It would be helpful in finding a better word if you could provide more background for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

How about "bucket"?

You can think of it in terms of bucket count and bucket size.
Visualizing a line of shot glasses vs a line of garbage cans (bins to the British speakers).